# Would build cleaning wipe out also local storage?

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-8, windows-8.1

If I build a windows 8 / windows Phone 8 app that's got some local storage, if I clean the build will it actually clean the local storage also ?

Comment: I don't think so. It won't. Assuming that you are deploying the app on a device while debugging..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Windows Phone 8:**

"Clean Solution" will not clean local app data, however a Rebuild solution does.

**Windows Store:**

*Q. How is app data affected during development with multiple build/deploy cycles?*

A. As you develop an app, app data is normally preserved across build iterations. However, changing the manifest triggers a full uninstall and redeployment from within Visual Studio, and that deletes any existing app data. To manually preserve that app data, copy the contents of the %localappdata%packagesfolder to a temporary location, build and redeploy the app, and then copy the app data back. Note that this redeployment behavior in Visual Studio is a separate matter from updating an app from the Store or via side-loading, in which case the deployment engine does not uninstall the previous version and app data is therefore preserved.

[Source](http://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2014/06/19/common-questions-and-answers-about-files-and-app-data-part-1-app-data/)

Answer (score 2):

At least for Windows Phone, if you do a "Rebuild" and then deploy via Visual Studio then it will wipe local storage (not sure about Windows Store apps). If you want to avoid this, but you need to do a full re-build, you can use the [Isolated Storage Explorer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh286408(v=vs.105).aspx) to retrieve the data before re-deploying, then put it back later.

Note that this only applies to apps being deployed via VS for debugging; apps delivered via the Store retain their data.